# how I define XSD file to map item without namespace

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:getStudentResponse xmlns:ns2="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
        <ns2:student>
            <ns2:id>5</ns2:id>
            <ns2:contacs>malibag</ns2:contacs>
            <ns2:contacs>gulsan</ns2:contacs>
            <ns2:item>
                <key>accessCode</key>
                <value>8373</ns2:value>
            </ns2:item>
           </ns2:student>
    </ns2:getStudentResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

question is how I define XSD file to map item(key, value) without namespace in one page except import or include things.

Comment: @Michael Kay hey man, could you please help me.

Comment: It's a bad idea to ask one specific person for help because you have a good chance of everyone else ignoring your question. And I'm sorry, you're going to have to do a bit more work: give us your best efforts, explain where you got stuck, explain more clearly what your requirements and constraints are.

Comment: Thank you for valuable comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is your solution. Just add `form` and set `unqualified` for particular element in xml schema.

`<element name ="" form ="unqualified">`

Answer (score 0):

All of the components defined in your XSD are in the namespace defined by its targetNamespace. If your question how to get xml without prefixes ns2, you need to add **elementFormDefault="unqualified"** to the **xsd:schema** element of your source XSD.

For example, it can be added into complexType.

```
  <xsd:complexType name="item">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="key" type="xsd:string" form="unqualified"/>
      <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" form="unqualified"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Then you get the elements key and value without namespaces

Comment: I have two elements inside my xsd file. But i want one element without namespace. how can i achieve it.

Comment: Could you attach your xsd and an example of an element you're expecting without a namespace?

Comment: He just need to one specific element without namespace eg. <item> as he showed in question